# Creating a password-protected account for non-enterprise Memgraph instance

Tags: memgraphdb

I am using Memgraph 2.1.1 and I am wondering if there's any way to set the password for my non-enterprise instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic authentication is supported in the non-enterprise version. You should be able to create a password-protected user with the following query:

```
CREATE USER user_name [IDENTIFIED BY 'password'];
```

For example:

```
CREATE USER my_user IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
```

When you create the first user, it won't be possible to connect to the instance without valid credentials.